# Is it possible to find max. value from a Histogram

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

Using grafana-agent to scrape the metrics from my application. I wonder if it's possible to gather max. value within a histogram by using PromQL. I have been publishing execution time metrics in an Histogram from my application, but I would like to also get the max. value like max. execution time within/per minute. I wonder if this is possible by Histogram and PromQL or should I consider a customized solution for that?

Thanks,

- No min/max value sent via Prometheus Histograms so considering custom solution(s) to publish the max. value of a metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query for obtaining the **estimated** maximum value from [histogram](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#histogram) metric with the name `foo` over the last hour:

```
histogram_quantile(1, increase(foo_bucket[1h]))
```

Note that the `_bucket` suffix is added to the `foo` histogram name in the query.

This query uses the [histogram_quantile](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#histogram_quantile) function for calculating the **estimated** maximum value seen during the last hour (see `1h` in square brackets in the query above). The estimation error can be quite big if the maximum observed value is located too far from the configured histogram bucket bounds. See [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/improving-histogram-usability-for-prometheus-and-grafana-bc7e5df0e350) for details and possible solutions on how to reduce the estimation error.

Comment: Thanks @valyala for this answer. Unfortunately, `estimated` part requires fine tuning of bucket cardinality and range. Not a perfect solution, but all we have I think with histograms.

Comment: That's unfortunate. It makes sense to automatically add the "max, min, sum, count" to the histogram, so we don't have to add more code to do that separately.